# Move column level to top in multi column index pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, multi-index

What's a pythonic way to move a certain column level to the top in a pandas multi column index?

Toy example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [
        ["a1", "a1", "a1", "a1"],
        ["b1", "b1", "b2", "b2"],
        ["x1", "x1", "x1", "x1"],
        ["c1", "c1", "c1", "c1"],
    ],
    names=(
        "unknown_level_name_0",
        "unknown_level_name_1",
        "known_level_name",
        "unknown_level_name_last",
    ),
)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, [5, 4]), columns=cols)

print(df)

unknown_level_name_0     a1            
unknown_level_name_1     b1      b2    
known_level_name         x1      x1    
unknown_level_name_last  c1  c1  c1  c1
0                        37  34  97  19
1                        54  47  53  46
2                        63  94  14  85
3                        16  51  27  96
4                        32  64  76  26
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
known_level_name         x1      x1    
unknown_level_name_0     a1            
unknown_level_name_1     b1      b2    
unknown_level_name_last  c1  c1  c1  c1
0                        37  34  97  19
1                        54  47  53  46
2                        63  94  14  85
3                        16  51  27  96
4                        32  64  76  26
```

EDIT:
There can be a variable number of levels. Most level names are unknown. However, there will always be one familiar level name (here: "known_level_name").
Using `reorder_levels` or `swaplevel` might become tricky if I don't know the exact position of "known_level_name".

Comment: you don't need to know the names, just the indices.

Comment: I wrote a [small function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514431/16343464) to make moving to the top automated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic function to move a column level (by label or index) to the top:

```
def move_top(df, col, inplace=False):
    if col in df.columns.names:
        idx = df.columns.names.index(col)
    elif isinstance(col, int) and 0 < col < len(df.columns.names):
        idx = col
    else:
        raise IndexError(f'invalid index "{col}"')
    order = list(range(len(df.columns.names)))
    order.pop(idx)
    order = [idx]+order
    if inplace:
        df.columns = df.columns.reorder_levels(order=order)
    else:
        return df.reorder_levels(order, axis=1)
    
move_top(df, 'known_level_name')
```

output:

```
known_level_name         x1            
unknown_level_name_0     a1            
unknown_level_name_1     b1      b2    
unknown_level_name_last  c1  c1  c1  c1
0                        33  30  23  77
1                        10  73  80  33
2                         7  54  52   9
3                        71  99  22  22
4                        83  15  86  40
```

Comment: I like this solution. You could also allow for negative indexing, such as ``elif isinstance(col, int) and -len(df.columns.names) <= col < len(df.columns.names):``.

Comment: One more error, it should read: ``order = list(range(len(df.columns.names)))``

Comment: @Andy Yes there is room for improvement, one could also add a parameter to move to any position, not only the top. The goal was mostly to show a proof of concept ;)

Comment: You can make it a nice feature-full index method and submit a patch to pandas :p

Comment: I understood your proof of concept, that's why I marked it as the accepted answer ;-) I just highlighted the issues for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try `reorder_levels`

```
out = df.reorder_levels([2,0,1,3], axis=1)
Out[184]: 
known_level_name         x1            
unknown_level_name_0     a1            
unknown_level_name_1     b1      b2    
unknown_level_name_last  c1  c1  c1  c1
0                        98  32  72  94
1                        22  71  15   2
2                        25  41  42  38
3                        87  74  41  82
4                        87  31  18   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html) (also available as [DataFrame method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html)):

```
# by index
df.columns = df.columns.reorder_levels(order=[2,0,1,3])
```

or:

```
# by name
df.columns = df.columns.reorder_levels(order=['unknown_level_name_1',
                                              'known_level_name',
                                              'unknown_level_name_0',
                                              'unknown_level_name_last'
                                             ])
```

Alternative, multiple `swaplevel`:

```
   # move level 2 up    # move again up
df.swaplevel(2,1,axis=1).swaplevel(1,0,axis=1)
```

output:

```
known_level_name         x1            
unknown_level_name_0     a1            
unknown_level_name_1     b1      b2    
unknown_level_name_last  c1  c1  c1  c1
0                        17  68  61  88
1                         6  62  81   7
2                        82  16  85  92
3                        40  22  48   0
4                        35  46  68  60
```